# Is this textbook proof of the Third Homomorphism Theorem of groups correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading *Abstract Algebra*, 3rd edition by Herstein. On page 87 (in section 2.7) he states The Third Homomorphism Theorem like this:

> If the map $\phi:G \rightarrow G'$ is a homomorphism of $G$ onto $G'$ with kernel $K$ then, if $N' \lhd G'$ and $N = \{a \in G \mid \phi (a) \in N' \}$, we conclude that $G/N \simeq G'/N'$. Equivalently, $G/N \simeq (G/K)/(N/K)$.

He proves that $G/N \simeq G'/N'$ by defining the map $\psi:G \rightarrow G'/N'$ by $\psi(a) = N'\phi(a)$ and showing that it is a surjective homomorphism with kernel equal to $N$ and thus $G/N \simeq G'/N'$ by the First Homomorphism Theorem. This all is fine with me.

But as for the last statement of his theorem, he just says:

> Finally, again by Theorems 2.7.1 [the First Homomorphism Theorem] and 2.7.2 [The Correspondence Theorem], $G' \simeq G/K$, $N' \simeq N/K$, which leads us to $G/N \simeq G'/N' \simeq (G/K)/(N/K)$.

I understand that $G' \simeq G/K$ and $N' \simeq N/K$, but I don't see how that implies $G'/N' \simeq (G/K)/(N/K)$. I tried to prove this general theorem: If $A \lhd G, B \lhd H, A \simeq B$, and $G \simeq H$, then $G/A \simeq H/B$. Then I realized it's not true. A simple counterexample is given by $G = H = \mathbb{Z}$, $A = \mathbb{Z}$, and $B = 2\mathbb{Z}$.

Is Herstein mistakenly thinking that this statement to which I just provided a counterexample is a theorem? Or is there some other reason for his final conclusion?

By the way, I realized how to prove $G/N \simeq (G/K)/(N/K)$ directly without first proving $G/N \simeq G'/N'$ first. So, the validity of his original theorem is not an issue for me.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: The point is that the (canonical) isomorphism $G' \to G/K$ maps $N'$ isomorphically to $N/K$.

Comment: You could draw a diagram with $G \to H$ in the top row, $A \to B$ in the second row, and the inclusion maps $A \to G$ and $B \to H$ vertically—it's a square. The square has two routes from $A$ to $H$: either $A \to G \to H$, or $A \to B \to H$. We say the square *commutes* if these two compositions are equal. If the square commutes, then $G/A \cong H/B$. The square does not commute in your example (which is a very nice example!).

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Thanks. I see.

Comment: @Zach Teitler: I like that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the isomorphisms $\psi:G/K\to G'$ and $\psi_1:N/K\to N'$ are *connected*, because of the definition of $N$, namely $\psi_1$ is the *restriction* of $\psi$ to $N/K$. 
This additional condition allows you to prove the claim in itself.

Comment: Ahh, I see. That's very clear now. So the author is using the fact that if A is a normal subgroup of G, B is a normal subgroup of H, phi is an isomorphism of G into H, and phi(A) = B, then G/A is isomorphic to H/B, which is intuitively obvious (and easy to prove). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with your example is that the isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{2Z} $ is not a restriction of the isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ if you pick it to be the identity map. So in general, if $G \simeq H$ (via $\psi: G \rightarrow H$), $A \simeq B,$ where $A, B$ are normal subgroups of $G, H$ respectively, and $\psi(A)= B$, then you have a commutative diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
G @>{\psi}>> H\\
@VVV @VVV\\
G/A @>{\psi'}>> H/B
\end{CD}
where $\psi'$ is induced from $\psi$ by: $\psi'[g]= [\psi(g)]$, and if $[a] = [b]$ in $G/A$, then $ab^{-1} \in A$, which implies $\psi(ab^{-1})= \psi(a) \psi(b^{-1}) \in B$, which implies $\psi'$ is well defined and the diagram is commutative. Now, $\psi'$ is obviously onto since $\psi$ is an isomorphism and both quotient maps are onto. $\psi'$ is also injective since the kernel of $\psi'$ is {$[g]: \psi(g) \in B$}, which is the identity in $G/A$.

In your case, the restriction of the isomorphism  $G' \rightarrow G/K $ is $N' \rightarrow N/K$, so the claim is correct.